# How can I envision the open ball around the french railways metric?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have that the French railways metric defined by a metric space $(\mathbb{R}^2,d)$ has a distance function that is a metric as follows:

$$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} \|x-y\|, & \text{if $x,y,0$ are collinear;} \\
\|x\| +\|y\|, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

I am trying to find a way to describe the open ball $B_r(x)$ for $x \in M$ and for $r>0$. Would anyone be kind enough to help me envision or perhaps even give me a rough sketch of how this ball would look like? thank you!

Comment: lolipops with their centers at the origin

Comment: if you draw a line from origin to x, then you have the segment supported by this direction, of size $2r$ and centered on $x$ (corresponding to the collinear case). Else, for every other $y$, $d(x,y) \leq r \implies ||y|| \leq r - ||x||$ so if $r < ||x||$, this is it, and otherwise, you add an usual ball centered on origin of radius $r - ||x||$. So, as said buba, a kind of lolipop (notice that if $r$ is too small, you just have the stick that doesn't reach zero)

Comment: The open ball around the origin is the ordinary ball around the origin.

Comment: Also, I've never heard this called the "French railways" metric. I hear it called the "Paris Metro" metric. It's appropriate because the Paris Metro (subway) system really works this way -- if you want to go anywhere that's on another line, you first have to go to the central station. That's how it used to work, anyway. Maybe it has improved. I haven't been to Paris in the last few decades.

Comment: it actually comes from the railway system, as in 1856 if you wanted to go from strasbourg to lyon, youd have to take a 400km detour via paris (wikipedia)